# payment gateway library

Tags: payment-gateway

is there any free to use .net based payment gateways library (wrapper) which ease life to implement famous payment gateways like different methods of paypal, authorize.net, dodirect....?

Comment: Why bother?  All of the providers you mentioned have very simple to use APIs... It shouldn't take more than an hour or two to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Olvio Ecommerce for Authorize.NET](http://www.olvio.com/WebModules/Downloads/Free.aspx) is a free library that you can use for .NET (VB and C#) projects to access the Authorize.NET gateway. I've used it myself and although it is a bit dated, am still satisfied with how this product performs.

Answer (score 1):

[Braintree](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com) has an open source [.NET Library](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/gateway/dotnet). It's specific to Braintree though, so it won't work with other payment gateways.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with this E-Payment Integrator  which supports almost 70 gateways.. The trial version is free..

However since there is no free lunch, the full version has to be purchased..
http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/epayment/

Answer (score 0):

You will get the source code for any gateway for any platform in the help/documentation/ download sections of the payment gateway/payment processor website. Compile these codes and host it on codeplex.com. This will be the open source project you want...

And do remember to upgrade the code regularly, since the APIs for the payment gateways changes often for to security measures...